# GIS Route From and Returning to the Same Location returns Error

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling the flight path of a helicopter tour that departs from and returns to the same location using a GIS route and "home base" as a GIS point. When I run the model it  returns this error:
[image: Error Message]
Is there a script or a workaround to solve this? I hope to have the helicopter depart, return, wait, and then depart again via a statechart loop.

Comment: What happens if you put the start and end of the route a little farther? So that they don't overlap.

Comment: Works fine when I have the start and end point separate but not sure if I can have a loop without the start and end being the same point.

Comment: you need to give more info.. you are not doing any loop.. you are definitely trying to move the agent incorrectly to the same location it's already in... which is not something aligned with what you say you are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot move agents to their current position using a path. The concept of a "loop" does not exist.

So you can do 2 things:

- break up the GIS loop into 2 sections and make the agent move along each sequentially (arriving at the original place at the end)
- move your agent a tiny bit away from the original position and then make it move along the path